# Map an Input From Keyboard to a Position on Screen

Tags: input-devices

This is one complicated question, but here is what I am trying to accomplish.

I want to set the WASD keys and maybe others to a specific position on screen so that for example, if I press the W key, it would behave as if I clicked/touched/dragged in the position on screen X = 200, Y = 400.

**UPDATE 1**: I found a command called `xdotool` and more or less created the following:

`xdotool mousemove 712 818 mousedown 1 mousemove_relative 15 35 mousedown 1 sleep 0.1 mouseup 1`

This would click on the screen at that X / Y position when I press the letter S, drag the simulated mouse X + 15 & Y + 35 and then release the mouse. The problem is, I need to figure out a way for the release to happen when I stop pressing the letter S.

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: @David It actually would not matter. I am using 22.04, 22.10 and 23.04 for the tests here.